# browser not showing correct url even after using response.sendRedirect method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I went through several questions before asking, but i cannot find a proper answer.

I need to change my url in browser whenever i visit different page. I'm using `response.redirect` method for redirection of every page both in servlet and jsp. But only the page is redirected(content of that jsp is loaded successfully) and the url is not changing.

i have tried with

```
response.sendRedirect("/project-x/jsp/mymodule/page1.jsp");
```

even when i get to a page through anchor tags, the url is not changing. 
eg:

```
<a href ="/page2.jsp">anchor</a>
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: post some more code, what do you heva before and after this?

Comment: Was your latest code updated to the server  ?

Comment: You mean: the redirect succeeds (content is loaded), but in the navigation text box of the browser the URL is not updated?

Comment: Yes my content is loaded successfully. I can view that in my browser, with no errors. But the url remains unchanged.

Comment: Dou you have any Filters plugged in? Try to disable them.

Comment: I dont have any filters, my web.xml have only servlet mapping.

Comment: @OndrejBozek what is the relation between url change and Filter

Answer (score -1):

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/SomeServlet");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

use this using that you can change your URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It successfully forwards and the content is loaded. But still no luck. URL is not changing.

Comment: I wish to add few more details to my existing question. Inside my jsp page, i'm calling servlets to fetch some database values and returning back to same jsp page. I'm using response.redirect and also tried using getRequestDispatcher. But still,no luck. The content is successfully loaded, but my url doesnt change.

Comment: In IE8 when i goto properties(right-click->properties) of that page, my exact url address is shown there. But not in browser url.

Comment: Please put some code so that i can more focus on your question.